# UISpec4J File Chooser Testing

Tags: java, junit, uispec4j

I'm trying to use UISpec4J to test a file chooser. 
A button is supposed to make the file chooser pop up. I found an example for a file chooser that pops up from a menu option:

```
 WindowInterceptor
   .run(openMenu.triggerClick())
   .process(FileChooserHandler.init()
            .titleEquals("Select a template file")
            .assertAcceptsFilesOnly()
            .select("/home/bond/file.txt"))
   .run();
```

But I can't seem to get it to work with a simple button click instead - I know this is probably a really simple question but I can't seem to find other documentation to get this to work and I am pretty stuck... Can someone explain how to test this? Thanks!

Comment: What error is happeneing? This code looks ok. But my interceptors that use to work stopped once I move JDKs. Maybe this is something similar

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried example from [documentation](http://www.uispec4j.org/reports/apidocs/org/uispec4j/interception/FileChooserHandler.html) and failed. Little change could help:

```
WindowInterceptor
        .init(openMenu.triggerClick())
        .process(FileChooserHandler.init()
            .titleEquals("Select a template file")
            .assertAcceptsFilesOnly()
            .select("/home/bond/file.txt"))
            .run();
```

I've replaced first instance of **run** to **init**.
Probably, it's a typo in docs.